# State array not updating when removing an array item in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-effect

When I remove an array item from my state array, I'm also updating the prices after removing the array item. But prices are not updating. I have tried every thing, but didn't get any solution.

```
export default function CustomizerState(props) {
    const initialTextItem = {
        text: "Hello",
        neonPrice: 0,
        backplatePrice: 0,
        neonPower: 0,
        totalPrice: 0
    }
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
        textItems: [initialTextItem],
        libraryItems: [],
        accessories: [...],
        finalPrice: null
    })

    const removeItem = (id, itemType = "textItems") => {
        const filteredItems = settings[itemType].filter((item) => {
            return item.id !== id
        })
        setSettings((prevState) => (
            {...prevState, [itemType]: filteredItems}
        ))
        finalPrice()
    }

    const finalPrice = () => {
        const textItemsPrice = getTotalPrice()
        const libraryItemsPrice = getTotalPrice("libraryItems")
        const accessoriesPrice = getTotalPrice("accessories", "unitPrice")
        console.log(textItemsPrice, libraryItemsPrice, accessoriesPrice)

        const finalPrice = textItemsPrice + libraryItemsPrice + parseInt(accessoriesPrice)
        setSettings((prevState) => (
            {...prevState, finalPrice}
        ))
    }

    const getTotalPrice = (itemType = "textItems", priceKey = "totalPrice") => {
        let price = 0
        settings[itemType].map((item) => (
            price = price + (item[priceKey] * item.quantity)
        ))
        return price
    }

    return (
        <CustomizerContext.Provider value={{settings, addTextItem,
            removeItem}}>
            {props.children}
        </CustomizerContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

For now, it is behaving like when I remove any item, it doesn't update the `finalPrice` object item, but when I remove another item then it updates the prices for previous items. I don't know why it is behaving like this.

Can someone please have a look on my code and tell me what is wrong with it and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `finalPrice()`right after you set your state
that triggers a re-rendering. You have to trigger the change using `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  finalPrice()
}, [settings]
```

You should probably consider separating your price from the rest of your settings.

Comment: Oh man, why i forgot to add `settings` in array dependency. I hate when i forgot these small things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a function right after updating the list, do the calculations before and update the state altogether. The problem with your approach is that when the calculus is being made, the state haven't updated yet, so when the function `finalPrice()` runs it takes the previous value.

I sincerely recommend you to use a `Reducer` instead, a single state with so many parameters may be troublesome.

Refer to [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), it will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks brother, I will surely study `useReducer`